# Extract data from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

TABLE A

```
INV    AMT   DISC
1001  1500    150
1002  3000    300
```

TABLE B

```
INV  DESC        AMT
1001 CHARGES     100
1001 FREIGHT      30
1001 INSURANCE    20
1002 CHARGES     215
1002 FREIGHT      32
1002 INSURANCE    25
```

For Table B, I used the SQL here to convert row to column format:

```
SELECT t.inv,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.description = 'CHARGES' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) AS charges,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.description = 'FREIGHT' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) AS freight,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.description = 'INSURANCE' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) AS insurance
    FROM TABLE B
GROUP BY t.inv
ORDER BY t.inv
```

How can I combine the data into this format using SQL:

```
INV     AMT   DISC    CHARGES FREIGHT INSURANCE
1001   1500    150      100      30       20
1002   3000    300      215      32       25
```

Thanks.

Comment: and what are your problems and questions?

Comment: i need to hv in this format:-                                   INV AMT DISC CHARGES FREIGHT INSURANCE
1001 1500 150 100 30 20
1002 3000 300 215 32 25

Comment: state your question in your question, not in a comment! and make sure to explain what you tried so far and how you failed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join between Table A and you query against Table B

```
declare @TableA as table (inv int, amount int, disc int)
declare @TableB as table (inv int, description varchar(50), amount int)

insert into @TableA values (1001, 1500, 105)
insert into @TableA values (1002, 3000, 300)

insert into @TableB values (1001, 'CHARGES', 100)
insert into @TableB values (1001, 'FREIGHT', 30)
insert into @TableB values (1001, 'INSURANCE', 20)
insert into @TableB values (1002, 'CHARGES', 215)
insert into @TableB values (1002, 'FREIGHT', 32)
insert into @TableB values (1002, 'INSURANCE', 25)

select
    A.inv,
    A.amount,
    A.disc,
    B.charges,
    B.freight,
    B.insurance
from @TableA as A
    inner join (
                SELECT t.inv,
                       MAX(CASE WHEN t.description = 'CHARGES' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) AS charges,
                       MAX(CASE WHEN t.description = 'FREIGHT' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) AS freight,
                       MAX(CASE WHEN t.description = 'INSURANCE' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) AS insurance
                FROM @TableB as t
                GROUP BY t.inv) as B
        on A.inv = B.inv
where
    B.charges = 100 and
    A.inv = 1001
```

Output is

[image: Output from query]

Comment: Error: SQL0122 - Column FREIGHT or expression in SELECT list not valid. (State:S1000, Native Code: FFFFFF86) ???

Comment: It's ok. Found the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now that I hv combined them, how can I add say charges = '100' ? I hv tried using "where charges = '100'" and "where b.charges = '100'". Both methods do not produce any output.

Comment: @Bob: Added a where clause to select statement and showing the output.

Comment: i followed the above & it produced a blank output. Any reasons ?

Comment: Do you get a blank output when running the test code above? Just copy and paste the entire code to a new query window. As you can see it works for me.

Comment: It works with 'charges = 100' but when I added it with 'where charges = 100 and a.inv = 1001', blank output.

Comment: Non other than that your data does not have a `inv=1001` where `charges=100`. Remove the where clause and check manually for a row where inv is 1001 and charges is 100.

Comment: There is such transaction. If i insert it at "FROM @TableB as t where inv=100" and followed by "on A.inv = B.inv where charges = 100", it produces the result.

Comment: `inv=100` ? That explains why you don't find rows with `inv=1001`

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was when I typed it as inv=1001.

Comment: Remove the where clause and look for `inv=1001` where `charges=100`. Is it there? What result do you get? Perhaps the row where inv is 1001 you have a charges that is something else then 100.

Comment: It's there, inv=1001 where charges=100, when i searched it manually. If i removed it, it will list down all invs.

Comment: I have no idea what is going on at your system. These are regular where clauses applied to the result of the query. inv=1001 will show you all rows where inv is 1001. charges=100 will show you all rows where charges is 100. The combination of inv=1001 and charges = 100 will show you the rows where charges is 100 and inv is 1001.